# Missing records while inserting

Tags: java, mysql

I was trying to fetch data from one database and insert the data into the tables created in another database there were 86992 records on total which must be fetched and inserted I used jdbc and collections framework for this purpose but I was able to insert only 84726 and I found 2000+records missing

I tried many ways could not find the reason would be very thankful if anybody gives assistance thanks in advance. I cannot present my code as I made 15 classes in whole. My SQL queries are as follows:

For table names:

```
select * 
from sqldictionary 
where fieldid = 0;
```

(results all tables in database)

For attributes :

```
SELECT DField.* 
FROM SqlDictionary AS DTable, 
     SqlDictionary AS DField 
WHERE DTable.Name = '" + _entity.getName() + "' 
      AND DTable.FIeldID = 0  
      AND DField.tableid = dtable.tableid 
      AND dfield.fieldid <> 0 "  ;
```

Comment: are the tables and the contraints on them identical?

Comment: yes all the constraints are same

Answer (score 0):

i found the reason behind missing records, actually i need to transfer data from source db to target db. source db has 86992 records out which 2000+ records are repeated(duplicates), which are not allowed by code to insert in to target db (which was the requirement originally), i.e unique records must be exported to target db.